# Convert stored procedure which uses exec to populate table to scalar-valued function

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, user-defined-functions

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_checker2] 
    (@Item varchar(70), @location varchar(8))      
as      
    declare @Query varchar(2000)      
    set @location = 'XXX909'   

    declare @Table Table (Qty int)      
    set @Query = 'select TOP 1 * from openquery(xxxx,''SELECT NVL(b.t$st,0) from server.XXXXXID0001 a left join  
server.XXXXXID0002 b on a.t$item = b.t$item where b.t$cloc = '''''+ @location + ''''' and trim(a.t$item)='''''+ @Item + ''''''')'      

   insert into @Table exec (@Query)      
   if not exists (select * from @Table )
  begin
     set @Query = 'select TOP 1 * from openquery(xxxx,''SELECT NVL(b.t$st,0) from server.XXXXXID0001 a 
     left join server.XXXXXID0002 b on a.t$item = b.t$item where trim(a.t$item) = '''''+ @Item + ''''''' )'    

    insert into @Table exec (@Query)
    end
    select * from @Table
```

The thing is I am looking to a query `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT 
    column1, column2, column3, column4, 
    (EXEC [dbo].[sp_checker2] 'param1=value of column3', 'param2=another value') AS column5 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    column1 = 'data1' 
    AND column2 = 'data2' 
ORDER BY 
    column3
```

I know it is not possible to execute a stored procedure in a `SELECT` statement in SQL Server and the alternative I have is to convert the stored procedure to a function, but inside the stored procedure I have an `exec` to insert data into the table variable. Is there a way I can convert this stored procedure to a function ?

P.S. I only save one row in the variable table, ie: if item exists it saves its inventory: "6500"

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks @marc_s I will consider this important fact on my upcoming procedures.

Comment: You have top 1 in your queries but they have no order by. This means cannot be sure which row will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult. In a function it is not possible to execute dynamic SQL. I think it is only possible if the WHERE criteria are shifted. You'll be better able to evaluate what impact this has on the performance.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_checker2] (@item     varchar(70), 
                                    @location varchar(8))
  RETURNS @result TABLE (
                    Qty int
                  )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT
    INTO @result
         select TOP(1) qty
           from openquery(xxxx, 'SELECT NVL(b.t$st,0)  AS qty,
                                        b.t$cloc       AS location,
                                        trim(a.t$item) AS item
                                   from server.XXXXXID0001 a 
                                        left join server.XXXXXID0002 b 
                                               on a.t$item = b.t$item')
   where location =  @location
     and item     =  @item

  if not exists (select * from @result)
    INSERT
      INTO @result
           select TOP(1) qty 
             from openquery(xxxx, 'SELECT NVL(b.t$st,0)  AS qty,
                                          b.t$cloc       AS location,
                                          trim(a.t$item) AS item
                                     from server.XXXXXID0001 a 
                                          left join server.XXXXXID0002 b 
                                                 on a.t$item = b.t$item')
     where item =  @item

  RETURN
END

GO
```

Comment: This is a multi-statement table valued function and the performance is going to be pretty bad here.

Comment: it worked, but took 10 mins and 17 secs to complete. @fbcomps  is there any further chance that it could be optimized ? I really appreciate the effort

Comment: Is it not possible that the complete query runs in a stored procedure or is it that goal to integrate this into a view?